# Multi-lined (word wrap) select choices in angular-ui-select

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui

Is it possible to make the select choice in [angular-ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) multilined? I know that you can't do that in conventional select input, but here it must be possible. If you're CSS guru, the plunker is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/a3KlK8dKH3wwiiksDSn2?p=preview

```
<ui-select ng-model="address.selected"
             theme="bootstrap"
             ng-disabled="disabled"
             reset-search-input="false"
             style="width: 300px;">
 <ui-select-match placeholder="Enter an address...">{{$select.selected.formatted_address}}</ui-select-match>
 <ui-select-choices repeat="address in addresses track by $index"
             refresh="refreshAddresses($select.search)"
             refresh-delay="0">
      <div ng-bind-html="address.formatted_address | highlight: $select.search"></div>
 </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Comment: If you have preformatted multiline text, you can use <pre>{{text}}</pre> tag.

Comment: the second example in plunker is multilined

Comment: I mean the word wrapping inside the 'choices'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is due to CSS property white-space, which is set to nowrap in default ui-select stylesheet.

You can change this behavior by adding this to your custom css :

```
.ui-select-bootstrap .ui-select-choices-row > a{
    white-space: normal;
}
```

This will alter the behavior of all ui-select on your page. If you want to alter just one, you can wrap it in a div :

```
  <div class="multiline-select">
    <ui-select (...)>
      (...)
    </ui-select>
  </div>
```

and change your css selector

```
div.multiline-select .ui-select-bootstrap .ui-select-choices-row > a{
    white-space: normal;
}
```

I have forked your plunkr to show the result
http://plnkr.co/edit/IplCxLbnPoIW4TJx1HIx?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

For more recent versions of `ui-select` (i'm using 0.19.3) it looks like the `a` element has been replaced with `span`.

Also to get the word wrap and border to work correctly around `ui-select-match` in the bootstrap theme, the height from `.form-control` prevents the border from going around the new line so a second rule should be made:

```
div.multiline-select .ui-select-bootstrap .ui-select-choices-row > span {
    white-space: normal;
}

div.multiline-select .ui-select-bootstrap .ui-select-match > span.btn {
  white-space: normal;
  height: auto;
}
```

Working plunkr forked from Vincent's and updated to 0.19.3: http://plnkr.co/edit/XKAJ1gVj4uAukk7IaBd2?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

In looking at this, it seems to not work for the bootstrap style (which was the original question?)  It seems that with bootstrap it works for the drop-down, but not for the resulting box (where it overflows.)

This forked plunkr demonstrates:

http://plnkr.co/edit/fMMSKuPMZwjgVCfV4n6d?p=preview

Note: I changed this:

```
<ui-select ng-model="country.selected" theme="bootstrap" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 200px;">
```